# How to enable Java Spring security only on paths defined in certain controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I want to enable spring security using my custom filter but I found out that I'm not able to enable it only on the paths defined in my controller.

Here's my current SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .antMatcher("/api/v1/**").addFilterBefore(
                    new AuthenticationFilter(myAuthenticator()),
                    ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

    }
}
```

In my controller I have `/api/v1/user`, `/api/v1/user/{userId}`. When I try to access an invalid path e.g. `/api/v1/invalid`, I always get a 401 instead of 404 since any path starts with `/api/v1` will go through the AuthenticationFilter first. This also occurred when I try to use an unsupported HTTP method on an existing path, my application will return 401 rather than a 405.

I want to achieve something like adding an annotation on the controller level (or method level is also fine), and apply the Authentication filter only on the paths defined in that controller e.g.

```
@WhateverAnnotationWillAddFilterToThisController***
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1", produces = "application/json")
public interface LicensingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> user();

    @RequestMapping(value = "user/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<LicensingRequest> getUser(
        @PathVariable
        String userId);
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is correct and consistent because you have using `/api/v1/**` for security which is a broader path. Ideally the `AuthenticationFilter` always stays above a resource path to avoid access to the resource if not authenticated.

In order to get 404 what you do is using narrower path matching.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/user", "/api/v1/user/{userId}").addFilterBefore(
                    new AuthenticationFilter(myAuthenticator()),
                    ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

    }
}
```

If you want http method level restrictions, you must specify that as well.

Comment: Thanks! This will definitely work. But what I was trying to do was more like if there are 30 apis in a controller, it's very hard to specify all the paths and it's pretty easy to leave new apis unsecured if the developers forget to add it to the antMatchers. So if a class/controller level security exists, I can just secure it in the class level so that all the paths defined in that class will be secured, but not the unimplemented paths. Will that be possible?